# Cauchy sequences proof

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, proof-writing, metric-spaces

Let $A \subset l^{\infty}$ be a subset such that $A = \{\{a_n\}$ (for $n\geq 1) \subset \mathbb{R} : a_n \neq 0$ for finitely many $n\}$ (That is, it consists of sequences of reals with finitely many non-zero elements). Let $A$ be equipped with the metric $d_{\infty}$; that is, $d_{\infty}(a, b) = \sup_{n \geq 1} |a_n - b_n|$, where we have $a = a_n$ and $b = b_n$ being points in $A$. Let $\{a^i\} \subset A$ for $i \geq 1$ given by $a^i = (1, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{3}, ..., \frac{1}{i}, 0, 0, ...)$ be a sequence. Prove that $\{a^i\}$ is Cauchy and deduce that the metric space $(A, d_{\infty})$ is not complete.

I know that after proving that it is Cauchy, I will have found a Cauchy sequence that does not converge making the space not complete. But I am struggling to show that it is Cauchy. I have spent hours thinking about this problem but to no avail. Any assistance with a proof is much appreciated.

Edit: Something I just realized: Knowing that $l^{\infty}$ is complete and $A$ is a subspace then $A$ is closed if and only if $A$ is complete. Would it suffice to show that $A$ is not closed?

Edit 2: Someone mentioned this to me:

Note that $a_1$ = $(1, 0, 0, ...)$, $a_2$ = $(1, \frac{1}{2}, 0, 0, ...)$ and so on. Then

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} ||a_n - a|| = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sqrt{\sum_{j = n + 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{j^2}} = 0$$

So $a_n \rightarrow a$ in $l^{\infty}$ and $\{a_n\}$ is Cauchy. Is this valid? If so, could somebody elaborate?

Comment: For the first edit, yes, it would; the second part of the answer by **absolute0** does that, making the first part actually unnecessary. For Edit 2 I’m assuming that $a=\left\langle\frac1n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\right\rangle$. Then $\|a_n-a\|=\frac1{n+1}$, so $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\|a_n-a\|=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{n+1}=0\,;$$ the calculation that was mentioned to you is wrong for $\ell^\infty$. However, it is true that since the sequence converges in $\ell^\infty$, it must be Cauchy in any subspace of $\ell^\infty$ that contains it.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott So it's that simple? Are the other answers below correct proofs too?

Comment: Yes, they are; I corrected the one serious oversight in **absolute0**’s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $n>m$, if $a_n$ denotes a term of the sequence $\{a^n\}_n$,

$$\begin{align*}
&a_n-a_m\\
&=\left(1, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{3}, \cdots, \frac{1}{m}, \frac{1}{m+1}, \cdots, \frac{1}{n}, 0,0,0, \cdots\right)-\left(1, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{3}, \cdots, \frac{1}{m}, 0,0,0, \cdots\right)\\
&=\left(\underbrace{0,0,\cdots,0}_{m\text{ zeroes}},\frac{1}{m+1}, \cdots, \frac{1}{n}, 0,0,0, \cdots\right)\,.
\end{align*}$$

So $d_\infty(a^n, a^m)=\frac{1}{m+1} \rightarrow 0$ as $n, m \rightarrow \infty$.

$$\begin{align*}
&a_n-a\\
&=\left(1, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{3}, \cdots, \frac{1}{n}, 0,0,0, \cdots\right)-\left(1, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{3}, \cdots, \frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n+1},\cdots\right)\\
&=\left(\underbrace{0,0,\cdots,0}_{n\text{ zeroes}},-\frac{1}{n+1}, -\frac{1}{n+2}, \cdots\right),,
\end{align*}$$

so $d_\infty(a^n,a)=\frac{1}{n+1} \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

But $a=\left(1, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{3}, \cdots, \frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n+1},\cdots\right) \notin A$, hence $A$ isn't complete.

Comment: I made it a little easier to read and added the missing zeroes in the difference sequences. You should go back and add the definition of $a$ before you talk about it.

Comment: Got it. Thank you.

Comment: You’re welcome.

Comment: @absolute0 For the first part, why does it converge to $\frac{1}{m+1}$ and not $\frac{1}{n+1}$ as $m, n \rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: In my notation, for $n>m$, $d_\infty(a^n,a^m)=\sup_{n,m \geq 1} |a_n-a_m|=\sup_{n,m \geq 1} \{0, \frac{1}{m+1}, \frac{1}{m+2}, \cdots, \frac{1}{n} \}=\frac{1}{m+1}$. As you notice $\frac{1}{n+1}$ can't be the supremum here.

Answer (score 2):

We have $|a^i - a^j| \leq \frac{1}{\min(i, j)}$. Consider some $\epsilon > 0$. Take $N > \frac{1}{\epsilon}$, which exists by the Archimedean property. Then for all $i, j \geq N$, we have $|a^i - a^j| \leq \frac{1}{\min(i, j)} \leq \frac{1}{N} < \epsilon$.

Thus, the sequence is Cauchy.

Comment: I am a little confused. How do we know that $|a^i - a^j| \leq \frac{1}{min(i, j)}$?

Comment: Suppose WLOG that $i > j$. Then we see that the $k$th element of $|a^i - a^j|$ is $\frac{1}{k}$ if $i < k \leq j$ and $0$ otherwise. Then we have $\sup\limits_{k \in \mathbb{N}} |a^i - a^j|_k = \frac{1}{i + 1} \leq \frac{1}{\min(i, j)} = \frac{1}{i}$.